# Unable to stream RTSP using Live555 proxy server

Tags: tcp, udp, rtsp, vlc, live555

I am using Live555 streaming media for an application which records and re-streams RTSP streams coming from IP camera. For that, I am using openRTSP for recording and live555 proxy server for re-streaming the camera stream. For a few of the cameras we are facing a strange issue where in the camera recording happens successfully, however the live555 proxy server is unable to generate a new stream for the same camera stream (there is no indication of failure in the verbose output dump, however the rtsp url generated by proxy server cannot be decoded by an rtsp client). Since I do not have any idea about the live555 proxy server details, I have been unable to get into this problem. I tried streaming the same camera stream using VLC and that works fine. What could be possibly wrong with this. I am hereby attaching the verbose output for reference.

```
E:\...\live\proxyServer>live555ProxyServer.exe -V rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream
LIVE555 Proxy Server
        (LIVE555 Streaming Media library version 2012.05.17)

Opening connection to 10.17.10.67, port 554...
RTSP stream, proxying the stream "rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream"
        Play this stream using the URL "rtsp://10.17.1.150/proxyStream"

(We use port 8000 for optional RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling.)
...remote connection opened
Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)
Accept: application/sdp


Received 716 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 10:55:19 GMT
Content-Base: rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 540

v=0
o=- 1341385393116860 1 IN IP4 10.17.10.67
s=Session of first stream
i=First Codec Stream
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2007.08.03
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:Session of first stream
a=x-qt-text-inf:First Codec Stream
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=5;config=000001B005000001B509000001000000012000847A98
28A02240A31F
a=control:track1
m=metadata 0 RTP/AVP 97
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:97 METADATA/64000
a=control:track2

ProxyServerMediaSession["rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/"] added new
 "ProxyServerMediaSubsession" for RTP/video/MP4V-ES track
ProxyServerMediaSession["rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/"] added new
 "ProxyServerMediaSubsession" for RTP/metadata/METADATA track
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 122 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 10:55:56 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Opening connection to 10.17.10.67, port 554...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 122 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 10:56:48 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Opening connection to 10.17.10.67, port 554...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 122 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 5
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 10:57:43 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 122 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 6
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 10:58:23 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 122 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 7
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 10:59:04 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 8
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


ProxyRTSPClient["rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/"]: lost connection
to server ('errno': 10057).  Resetting...
Opening connection to 10.17.10.67, port 554...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 9
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 122 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 9
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 11:00:29 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Opening connection to 10.17.10.67, port 554...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 10
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 123 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 10
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 11:01:22 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 11
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 123 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 11
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 11:02:05 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 12
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 123 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 12
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 11:02:39 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 13
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 123 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 13
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 11:03:10 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE


Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.17.10.67/ch0_unicast_firststream/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 14
User-Agent: ProxyRTSPClient (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.05.17)


Received 123 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete OPTIONS response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 14
Date: Wed, Jul 04 2012 11:03:46 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE
```

Awaiting your response.

Regards,

Saurabh Gandhi

Comment: Do you use tcp transport? If yes please try with udp transport.

Answer (score 1):

It could be mostly because of udp ports blocked because of firewalls. Try `-t` flag to force the transmission through tcp.